# keep getting Node -1 disconnected

Tags: apache-kafka

Im using kafka and I keep getting this error messages . These are my logs :

```
Node -1 disconnected. 
14:30:07.192 trace-id: span-id: [kafka-producer-network-thread | telikos-activityplan-producer] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=telikos-activityplan-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. 
14:30:07.193 trace-id: span-id: [kafka-producer-network-thread | telikos-activityplan-producer] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=telikos-activityplan-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I have 0 idea what this is my kafka shows my broker & zookeper up and running. Some times it works (1/100) other wise it keeps showing disconnected.I am on Apple Silicon M1. Can it be a device specific issue?
In my docker All my broker zookeeper and schema registry are working fine

this is my docker file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeperap2
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: brokerap2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'


  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registryap2
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.0.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-centerap2
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
```

Comment: Sounds like your kafka container is failing... Provide server logs. Note that Confluent doesn't support arm devices with Docker until 7.3.1 images. Try upgrading.